# подписка на сигнал dbus

Tags: linux, c

Хочу подключиться к dbus network manager, но не пойму как, да и вроде я не правильно указываю параметры. Мне надо отлавливать сигналы о статусе, а именно сигнал "StateChanged". Вот что я смог всего лишь сделать и то не правильно.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <glib-2.0/gio/gio.h>

void interrupt ( int sig ) {
}

int main ( ) {
    signal ( SIGTERM, interrupt );

    GError *error = NULL;

    GDBusProxy *proxy = g_dbus_proxy_new_for_bus_sync (
            G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM,
            G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_NONE,
            NULL,
            "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active",
            "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Connection/Active",
            "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connection.Active",
            NULL,
            &error
            );

    while ( 1 ) { char c = getchar ( ); }

}
```

Или чтобы использовать сигналы, надо писать g_signal_connect? Хотя не, не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если полезли в Glib, то скорее всего прийдется запустить https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html

И да, нужен g_signal_connect, посмотрите примеры вроде https://github.com/MaZderMind/dbus-signal/blob/master/gdbus-example-peer.c#L241

Comment: О, спасибо.....